# I want making search filter in php. Session is not working for first time but Its running properly when second value passed

Tags: php, session

I am making search filter in php. But session is not working for first time. Its running properly after second time submission. the coding is like this:

```
session_start();
include('connect.php');
$select = "SELECT *";
$from = " FROM filter";
if($_POST)
    {
        $_SESSION['days'] = array();
        $_SESSION['WHERE'] = array();
        $day = $_POST['day'];
        $WHERE = $_SESSION['WHERE'];
        if($day!='')
            {
                foreach($day as $k)
                    {
                        array_push($_SESSION['days'],$k);
                        $Day[] = "dayId = $k";
                    }
                $WHERE[] = ' ('.implode(' OR ',$Day).')';
            }
        else
            {
                $WHERE[] = '';
            }
    }
if(!empty($_SESSION['days']))
    {
        foreach($_SESSION['days'] as $l)
            {
                ${m.$l} = 'checked = "checked"';
            }
    }
```

Comment: "Its running properly after second value passed" means form submission second time OR else?

Comment: Is `$day` a string or an array? `if ($day != '')` uses it as a string, but `foreach ($day as $k)` requires it to be an array.

Comment: empty($_SESSION['days']) check this with isset($_SESSION['days'] )

Comment: @SRK `empty` also checks if it's set, you don't need both.

Comment: $day is an array. and session is running after value submission second time.

Comment: @SRK thanks for your comment but i tried it, its not working